# What happens to apetite hormones like ghrelin and leptin when a person in coma?

Tags: human-biology, brain, endocrinology, human-physiology

Don't coma individuals feel hungry? If so, how does the brain senses this condition (as coma is caused by neural death or damage) and switches off gene expression of ghrelin and leptin.

Is there any research done on revealing the mechanism by which apetite hormones expression are shut down during brain death???

Thanks